# Unity build failed 'Gradle build failed. '

Tags: unity-game-engine, gradle

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.3f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.3f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-6.1.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleDebug"

stderr[
Note: D:\Freelance\FurryFriendFeeder\FurryFriendFeeder\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\Mono2x\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\unity3d\player\UnityPlayerActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:packageDebug'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key AndroidDebugKey from store "C:\Users\salih\.android\debug.keystore": Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUİLD FAILED in 22s
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
]

Observed package id 'platforms;android-30' in inconsistent location 'C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.3f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\Sdk\platforms\android-30' (Expected 'C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.3f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-30')
Already observed package id 'platforms;android-30' in 'C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.3f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-30'. Skipping duplicate at 'C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.3f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\Sdk\platforms\android-30'
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.3f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only

> Task :launcher:packageDebug FAILED
41 actionable tasks: 41 executed
]
exit code: 1
```

i can't resolve, How i can?

Answer (score 0):

Checking certain things may help:

1. Ensure that Android SDK, NDK and JDK are installed properly from the unity hub.
2. Check out the platforms folder & make sure that minimum & target API levels exist in this folder in the android sdk folder.
3. The error seems to be because of apk signing. Take a look at key store settings and make sure that the key store assigned exists.
4. Also, connecting to a good network connection can resolve some android build errors. Because unity sometimes downloads missing things of your build requirements from the internet.